# Sort column based on another that has already been sorted

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 37 | +6 |
| 23 | +9 |
| 51 | +13 |
| 37 | -14 |
| 23 | -17 |
| 51 | -20 |

I need `df$Value` to be sorted so it'll look like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 37 | +6 |
| 37 | -14 |
| 23 | +9 |
| 23 | -17 |
| 51 | +13 |
| 51 | -20 |

Because it's important to keep the first column's order.

Would anyone know how to help me? I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set `ID` as factor, then `arrange` on `Value`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(ID = factor(ID, levels = unique(ID))) %>% arrange(ID, desc(Value))

  ID Value
1 37     6
2 37   -14
3 23     9
4 23   -17
5 51    13
6 51   -20
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R option

```
> with(df, df[order(match(ID, unique(ID)), -Value), ])
  ID Value
1 37     6
4 37   -14
2 23     9
5 23   -17
3 51    13
6 51   -20
```

Answer (score 0):

First a reproducable example, here is a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID= c(17,18,17,19,19,18), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Then I am grouping by the ID and arrange the columns

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(ID)%>%arrange(ID, value)
```

If you dont have dplyr installed:

```
install.packages('dplyr')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   A [3]
      A value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    17     1
2    17     3
3    18     2
4    18     6
5    19     4
6    19     5
```